# how to remove this? mass remove on regex

Tags: regex

I have a twitter account data, and I want to delete the list who die and take account of life, how to remove with regex please with demo on regex101?

example :

```
Live! => [ elfiegoh@gmail.com:hawkhgaw ] + [Name: kyandenohime - Following: 31 - Follower: 4 - Bio: Hello there ! ◉‿◉ ☆welcome to my personal art dump★ - Art trades and requests open - Requests :18 ~ - Location: Empty - URL: Empty - Translator: No - Verified: No (Joined At Fri Dec 06 15:12:42 +0000 2013 [472 Days])]
Die! => [ hemiao01@gmail.com:takumimisaki ]
Live! => [ angie2002.stanford@gmail.com:cihuyers ] + [Name: һ∆яՊʘŋყ ʂƿ∆яҝ - Following: 7 - Follower: 0 - Bio: I am a - ժєՊⅈ₲ʘժ - ʂһ∆ժʘωһʊŋϮєя -ⅈŋⅈϮⅈ∆Ϯє -ƿʘϮϮєяһє∆ժ -ϮяⅈɞʊϮє -һєϮ∆ℓⅈ∆ŋ -Ϯһяʘŋєя -Ϯʄⅈʘʂ ʄ∆ŋ - Location: Empty - URL: Empty - Translator: No - Verified: No (Joined At Sat Jun 18 12:11:09 +0000 2011 [1374 Days])]
Die! => [ farissirraj@gmail.com:jujulisirraj ]
Die! => [ liu_shumin_vanessa@moe.edu.sg:8522735 ]
Die! => [ backdoor@windowslive.com:123456 ]
Die! => [ asdf@asd.com:123456789 ]
Die! => [ progpro19@gmail.com:sami ]
```

I want to delete the list with mass die, because I have a lot of accounts
after delete :

```
Live! => [ elfiegoh@gmail.com:hawkhgaw ] + [Name: kyandenohime - Following: 31 - Follower: 4 - Bio: Hello there ! ◉‿◉ ☆welcome to my personal art dump★ - Art trades and requests open - Requests :18 ~ - Location: Empty - URL: Empty - Translator: No - Verified: No (Joined At Fri Dec 06 15:12:42 +0000 2013 [472 Days])]
Live! => [ angie2002.stanford@gmail.com:cihuyers ] + [Name: һ∆яՊʘŋყ ʂƿ∆яҝ - Following: 7 - Follower: 0 - Bio: I am a - ժєՊⅈ₲ʘժ - ʂһ∆ժʘωһʊŋϮєя -ⅈŋⅈϮⅈ∆Ϯє -ƿʘϮϮєяһє∆ժ -ϮяⅈɞʊϮє -һєϮ∆ℓⅈ∆ŋ -Ϯһяʘŋєя -Ϯʄⅈʘʂ ʄ∆ŋ - Location: Empty - URL: Empty - Translator: No - Verified: No (Joined At Sat Jun 18 12:11:09 +0000 2011 [1374 Days])]
```

Comment: Really not cool from your part to post your users/clients email addresses on a public website. Try to post dummy data next time...

Comment: this is fake password sir :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^Die.*?(?:\n|$)
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tJ2mW5/15

Comment: there is still a new line left

Comment: Die! => [ 3chua.tzexi@beaconpri.sg:digitalartwork ]
Die! => [ karoline1122@hotmail.com:yellowwish ]
Die! => [ arlyno22@gmail.com:Metamorphosis11 ]
Live! => [ jackyc_97@hotmail.com:annie86. ] + [Fail! (Error) Reason: Login Email Challenge]

how to clean Live! => [ jackyc_97@hotmail.com:annie86. ] + [Fail! (Error) Reason: Login Email Challenge]

Comment: @ĽawrenceTReěve didnt get you